# NameError: global name 'balanceAr' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I get the following error (last line is important) for the code below:

> Warning (from warnings module):
> File "C:/[file_location]/itteration 4.py", line 12
>
> avgNug = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
>
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/[file_location]/itteration 4.py", line 45, in
>
> threshold(iar4)
>
> File "C:/[file_location]/itteration 4.py", line 13, in threshold
>
> balanceAr.append(avgNum)
>
> NameError: global name 'balanceAr' is not defined

I've tried writing "global" before it, defining it outside the definition is in, with multiple syntaxes for the "global" definition.

The code is taken from the sentdex video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nych18rsXKU where this code works.

I'm using the same Python version as him, and I'm assuming the same libraries, since this is the fourth program from the playlist, and the previous 3 worked fine.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def threshold(imageArray):
balaceAr = []
newAr = imageArray

    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNug = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
    balance = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, balanceAr)/len(balanceAr)

    for eachRow in newAr:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
                #eachPix 0,1,2,3 = 255
            else:
                #eachPix 0,1,2 = 0
                eachPix[3] = 255

    return newAr

'''in the original code this part is not commented, and there's also a i, i2 and i3
i4 = Image.open('images/sentdex.png')
iar4 = np.array(i4)'''

threshold(iar4)

'''same explanation as previous comment, only coordinates in 2nd () are 0,0;4,0;0,3
fig = plt.figure()
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,3), rowspan=4, colspan=3)

ax4.imshow(iar4)
'''

plt.show()

#P.S. I had to write "    " on all lines that didn't have it for stackoverflow
# to interpret it as code, even if it was in the "code" section
```

Comment: Could it really be just that you misspelled `balanceAr` as `balaceAr` in the first line of the function?

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error on decalration `balaceAr = []`

you may need to change it to `balanceAr= []`

Comment: Thank you. It's my first time using Python, and it's very... very picky about typos.

Comment: Wait... I changed it... something worked once, then gave the same error.

Comment: Found it. The "balanceAr = []" is not a syntax error, but notice there's a "avgNug", instead of a "avgNum" in the code.

Why I didn't notice is that it's the second time I write the code from scratch, and I got the same error last time.

Comment: @ZoltanTorok you need to decalare  something like this `avgNug = 0` under `balanceAr= []` because python trying to find the variable and not found so it throw error

also i see that you will use `balance` in the for loop so you will get another error, declare too `balance = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Below your function definition:

```
balaceAr = [] # <===== Typo
```

Check for typos before posting next time.

Comment: Because I did check, and it's the exact same spelling as the tutorial video... in which it worked.

Comment: There is a typo, it's just it isn't there. Because "balanceAr = []" works just fine after I found what was wrong.